# How to check whether Nodejs node modules are installed or not in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have developed a sample Node JS application , and have deployed in Heroku.
When I check the application in browser , due to some reason , which I am not aware of , it displays a JavaScript error in browser.

Now I would like to confirm whether all the node modules  have been installed or not , any idea how to check that ?

Note : Application runs without issues locally in my system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spin up a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos), in which you can list your node modules, as follows:

```
heroku run bash
npm list
```

Comment: Alternatively: `yarn list`